# How can we implement selenium grid in protractor

Tags: protractor

I am using protractor 5.2.2. with cucumber 3.2. I need to implement selenium grid in protractor for running multiple instances.So i need to configure one hub and a no.of nodes.So that we should be able to specify some particular parameters for corresponding nodes.How can we setup this hub and node configuration.When i searched about this, i got a link "https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-grid" of npm-selenium grid.Can we use this one for running multiple instances in one or different machines.Can anyone give the correct direction about this.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38183013/6205848

Answer (score 0):

Try out this : http://txt.fliglio.com/2014/01/concurrent-protractor-testing/. This will help you in running multiple instances. It has also explained to configure hub with nodes.

Comment: can we implement this selenium grid with other than docker?

Answer (score 0):

take a look at [Selenoid](https://aerokube.com/selenoid/latest/) tool. It easy to setup and it is much more solid than Selenium Grid implementation.